# jQuery : Sum multiple select value

Tags: jquery, html

how can I sum the value after "|" tag of myselect

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <select multiple class="form-control" id="multipleSelect" name="myselect[]">
<option value="X12SO|10">X12SO</option>
<option value="X13SO|20">X13SO</option>
<option value="X14SO|30">X14SO</option>
<option value="X15SO|40">X15SO</option>
<option value="X16SO|50">X16SO</option>
```

and get the live reslut on myresult with simple jquery code

```
<input type="text" name="myresult">
```

with simple jquery code

```
let sum = 0;
    $("#multipleSelect :selected").each(function(){
      sum += +this.value.split("|")[1];
    });
    $("input[name='myresult']").val(sum);
```

Comment: What is `myresult ` and what have you tried?

Comment: I'm already edited my question, I try to get the sum of **myselect** after "|" tag in value and get the result on **myresult**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate on all the options and get the cumulative value. Set this sum as the value of `input`.

```js
let sum = 0;
$("select[name='myselect'] option").each(function(){
  sum += +this.value.split("|")[1];
});
$("input[name='myresult']").val(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple class="form-control" name="myselect">
  <option value="X12SO|10">X12SO</option>
  <option value="X13SO|20">X12SO</option>
  <option value="X14SO|30">X12SO</option>
  <option value="X15SO|40">X12SO</option>
  <option value="X16SO|50">X12SO</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="myresult">
```

Comment: can I get the dynamic result of sum only if I selected the option?